# How to work with Decimal number on MariaDB

Tags: jdbc, mariadb

I am using MariaDB with JDBC.

Following is my table DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE Test_DataType_Number  
(   
   dataType_Number_1 decimal(1,0),
   dataType_Number_2 decimal(2,0),
   dataType_Number_3 int(10),
   dataType_Number_4 decimal(14,10), --  dataType_Number_4 NUMBER(4,10) used in Oracle
   dataType_Number_5 int(10),
   dataType_Number_10 int(10), 
   dataType_Number_14 decimal(14,4), -- dataType_Number_14 NUMBER(14,4) used in Oracle
   dataType_Number_20 bigint(19),
   dataType_Number_38 bigint(38)
);
```

Sample insert record:

```
INSERT INTO test_datatype_number
(dataType_Number_1, dataType_Number_2, dataType_Number_3, dataType_Number_4, dataType_Number_5, dataType_Number_10, dataType_Number_14, dataType_Number_20, dataType_Number_38)
VALUES(1, 12,123,0,12234,1234567890,1234567876.554,103339998820,103339998838);
```

I have written JDBC code to get these values:

```
//connection object created with MariaDB
Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
while (rs.next()) {
    myProperties.put("dataType_Number_1", rs.getString("dataType_Number_1"));
    myProperties.put("dataType_Number_2", rs.getString("dataType_Number_2"));
    myProperties.put("dataType_Number_3", rs.getString("dataType_Number_3"));
    myProperties.put("dataType_Number_4", rs.getString("dataType_Number_4"));
    myProperties.put("dataType_Number_5", rs.getString("dataType_Number_5"));
    myProperties.put("dataType_Number_10", rs.getString("dataType_Number_10"));
    myProperties.put("dataType_Number_14", rs.getString("dataType_Number_14"));
    myProperties.put("dataType_Number_20", rs.getString("dataType_Number_20"));
    myProperties.put("dataType_Number_38", rs.getString("dataType_Number_38"));

}
Enumeration<String> enums = (Enumeration<String>) myProperties.propertyNames();

while (enums.hasMoreElements()) {
    String key = enums.nextElement();
    String value = myProperties.getProperty(key);
    System.out.println(key + " : " + value);
}
```

Following is my output:

```
dataType_Number_10 : 1234567890
dataType_Number_5 : 12234
dataType_Number_4 : 0E-10
dataType_Number_3 : 123
dataType_Number_2 : 12
dataType_Number_1 : 1
dataType_Number_20 : 103339998820
dataType_Number_14 : 1234567876.5540
dataType_Number_38 : 103339998838
```

We can see values of dataType_Number_4  and dataType_Number_14 , one 0E-10 and other is 1234567876.5540. Why am I getting appended 0 or 0E-10 values? When I run the same program with Oracle (after creating and inserting same record in table), I'm getting the proper result.

Result with Oracle:

```
dataType_Number_10 : 1234567890
dataType_Number_5 : 12234
dataType_Number_4 : 0
dataType_Number_3 : 123
dataType_Number_2 : 12
dataType_Number_1 : 1
dataType_Number_20 : 103339998820
dataType_Number_14 : 1234567876.554
dataType_Number_38 : 103339998838
```

Please suggest what data type should I use in MariaDB to avoid this 0E-10 and appended 0.

Comment: Assuming the driver returns java.lang.BigDecimal, it could be a presentation problem. By using `rs.getString()` you get the default presentation returned by `toString()` . [The docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#toString()) say the output could include scientific notation (0E-10) *"...Returns the string representation of this BigDecimal, using scientific notation if an exponent is needed. ...." , IIRC, if you want the number formatted a specific way, you have to do it yourself.  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html

Comment: I second SOS' suggestion: use `getBigDecimal` and format the number appropriately. That way you can be sure it is consistent, otherwise you're relying on the driver specific implementation of `ResultSet.getString`.